# Why do political parties sign "agreements" with other foreign political parties?

Tags: international-relations, parties

In this [news article](https://www.politico.eu/article/hungaria-austria-herbert-kickl-watch-out-ukraine-here-comes-the-hungaro-austrian-empire/), it is mentioned that the *Freedom Party* of Austria has signed a "partnership agreement" with the *United Russia Party* of the Russian Federation:

> The Freedom Party ... has longstanding ties to Russia. Strache signed a partnership agreement with Putin’s United Russia party in 2016.

This is not uncommon.

In August 2008, India's oldest political party - *the Indian National Congress* - has also [signed a "Memorandum of Understanding"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/2008_Memorandum_between_the_Chinese_Communist_Party_and_the_Indian_National_Congress) with the Chinese Communist Party (CCP) of the People's Republic of China.

In both cases, this wasn't an agreement between foreign governments, but a party-to-party agreement. Often, these agreements aren't made public (similar to some foreign government contracts).

My question is why do foreign political parties need to sign such agreements between themselves, that may or may not involve consultation with their own government, and what are these "agreements" about?

*(Note that I do not attribute any malice, or accusations of indulging in "anti-national" activities to these acts. But I am interested to know about the motivations, and the international history, if any, behind such political actions.)*

Comment: It's for the same reasons that any private organization (and yes, political parties are private organizations) makes agreements with foreign organizations: common interests, mutual aid and support, coordinated efforts... IT may or may not ne legal, it may or may not be ethical, but there's nothing particularly mysterious about it.

Comment: @TedWrigley, no, in many parts of the world political parties are *not* private organizations. They have special privileges and duties.

Comment: @TedWrigley If there isn't anything "mysterious" why are some of these agreements confidential, and not public?

Comment: @o.m.: Odd that I wasn't aware of that.  can you give an example?

Comment: @sfxedit: short answer: politics. Sometimes agreements like that are politically beneficial if they're publicized. Sometimes (even if the agreements are not illegal or unethical) the groups don't want to show their hand to their political opponents.

Comment: @TedWrigley, Germany, political parties are required to have an *internal* democratic structure, they have financial reporting requirements different from other non-profits, they get government funding to match some donations, and they are constitutionally protected from government interference unless the supreme court finds them to be undermining the constitutional order. Taken together, I would not characterize them as "private organizations." Or, to take a different example, there is the DPRK, where the party is deeply integrated into the state. Again, no "private organization."

Comment: I wonder what motivates the downvotes?  Bad subject?  Phrasing?  It does seem very odd for a party to formally "buddy up" with another in another country, especially when country-to-country relations are not cordial (India-China above):  traditionally, that would have been the "kiss of death".  Seems on topic enough here.

Comment: @o.m.: interesting.  And I like it.  I wish it were that way in the US

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: is suspect that the examples chosen give an impression of bias (Putin's regime and the CCCP are triggers for many people). Granted, I'm not entirely convinced this is a proper question here, since it is only tangentially political, but I don't think it merits downvoting

Comment: @TedWrigley, if you are interested in political trivia, you might look at the German party Die PARTEI (The PARTY), founded by staff from a satire magazine and taking extreme pains to assure that they meet all the formal requirements of being a political party. Less funny, in the recent state-level elections in Bremen two rival factions of the AfD submitted different lists of candidates. The election officials rejected both of lists since they had no legal power to evaluate *which* of the two lists (and two groups of rival party officials) was the right one.

Comment: This is too broad of a question IMHO. There can be different reasons for different kinds of agreements. Why not focus on one of the two cases you mentioned?

Comment: @einsupportsModeratorStrike A list of those reasons with very brief explanation would be acceptable and not so hard.

Comment: Running a party involves a lot of organisation, and it probably makes sense to share expertise and effort. There may be scope for common research, conceiving strategies that would work in both countries, or shared international fact-finding missions; organising shared conferences, meetings, training, and other events; sharing staff or expertise in areas such as administration, candidate selection/vetting, design/communications/advertising; etc. You'd need to look at individual agreements to see what is actually covered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might compare this with the concept of [Track 1, Track 1.5, and Track 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Track_II_diplomacy) negotiations. When governments talk to each other, it is Track 1 and highly official. Academics and civil society are Track 2 and not official. Parties with government ties could be seen as something like Track 1.5.

In the [european-union](/questions/tagged/european-union), there are different political parties in each country which organize themselves into groupings in the European Parliament, e.g. the [EPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_People%27s_Party) on the center-right, the [PES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Party_of_European_Socialists) on the center-left, [ALDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alliance_of_Liberals_and_Democrats_for_Europe_Party) for european-style liberalism, or the [EGP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Green_Party) for the Greens. The individual members of these groupings are quite diverse; just consider how long it took the EPP to throw out [Fidesz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fidesz).

Similar groupings and associations exist beyond the borders of the EU. PES membership overlaps with the [Socialist International](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socialist_International), and EPP membership overlaps with the [Centrist Democrat International](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrist_Democrat_International).

In many countries there is the *political tradition* to keep domestic politics inside and to stand together on the international stage. This is crumbling in the EU, where, say, German conservatives might make common cause with Austrian conservatives against the German socialists, and not see that as unpatriotic or illegitimate.

Another example from German history has a more antagonistic situation. After WWII, Germany was split into four occupation zones for the Soviets, US, UK, and France, and eastern areas seized by the Soviets and Poland. The three occupation zones in the West became the Federal German Republic (FRG) and the occupation zone in the East became the German Democratic Republic (GDR). The FRG always insisted that this division was just temporary, and in the meantime it pressured third parties to accept only the FRG as representative of Germany (the [Hallstein doctrine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hallstein_Doctrine)). The two Germanies wanted to talk on practical and [humanitarian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Westpaket) issues, yet the FRG never admitted that their diplomats in East Berlin could be an embassy with an ambassador -- it had to be a mere [permanent representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_facto_embassy#West_Germany_and_East_Germany).

In the years before the permanent representation, when the FRG *government* tiptoed around anything resembling a recognition of the GDR, it was possible to have talks and letters between the Western SPD party and the Eastern SED party. These were understood to be somewhat substantial -- both parties played key roles in the respective states -- yet formally not state-to-state talks.

There are other countries, often authoritarian ones, where international cooperation gets labelled as *foreign agents* and suppressed.

And other cases where foreign parties are supported not because of a common ideology, but to [destabilize another country](https://www.dw.com/en/report-afd-members-flight-sponsored-with-russian-money/a-43872774).

Comment: I can understand agreements made with international alliances or alliances within alliances (like in EU), to promote certain political ideologies. But what kind of agreement can be between parties in two countries that don't necessarily have good relations each other, or have diametric political ideologies (like the INC in India and CCP in China), that cannot be made directly with the government?

Comment: @sfxedit, speaking generally, and not to the Chinese example, the cooperation of parties rather than governments helps to form an international civil society. Conservatives from a non-conservative country might talk to conservatives from a conservative country to promote conservative ideas, rather than one country or the other. The China example is problematic because China does not have an effective multi-party system. So the distinction of "we speak to/for the party, not the state" may be lost.

Comment: I got some insights from these 2 articles - https://www.indiatoday.in/latest-headlines/story/congress-chinese-communist-party-sign-mou-28102-2008-08-07 and https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/news/politics-and-nation/indian-national-congress-and-african-national-congress-sign-mou-to-boost-ties/articleshow/3118157.cms ... maybe you can include that to add to your answer, and if no one else provides a better answer, I'll mark your answer accepted.

Answer (score 1):

**Coordinating policy**
As it has been already pointed out in the other answer, this makes a lot of sense on the scale of the European union, where the parties partially share common playing field - both in the European parliament, but also in terms of influencing their government policy, which ultimately influences the European one.

To a lesser extent this is also true when speaking about Russian and western parties - Russia benefits from such alliances, because they either distabilize western governments or make them shift to the right and adopt more conciliatory policies vis-à-vis Russia. European parties usually benefit financially, but also by getting an image of peacemakers/conciliators or simply by stressing their anti-establishment credentials. (This is unlike the Soviet support for various Communist and Socialist parties during the Soviet time, though perhaps with less ideological reasons, and less direct control from the side of Russia.)

**Communist International**
The idea of coordinated policy is not new. A well-known example is the successive Communist Internationals, which were unions of trade-unions, small political parties and some illegal groups from various countries, agreeing on the common policy, intended to eventually benefit all of them (until Stalin managed to completely subjugate all of them to the directives from Moscow.)

**Secret pacts**
The policy is not uncommon even on the state level. As an example, one could consider [Sykes-Picot agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sykes%E2%80%93Picot_Agreement) and similar [secret protocol to the Molotov-Ribbentrop pact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molotov%E2%80%93Ribbentrop_Pact#Secret_protocol). Perhaps the incredulity that arises about such agreements is fully expose here: if the agreement is secret, how can it be enforced? (Given that enforcing anything in international politics is already hard.) In my opinion, such agreements are mainly concluded in order to achieve mutual understanding ("the spheres of influence") and thus avoid unnecessary and expensive infighting. E.g., [the secret protocol to the Molotov-Ribbentrop had to undergo several adjustments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molotov%E2%80%93Ribbentrop_Pact#Modification_of_secret_protocols), to reflect the changing realities on the ground, where the Nazis occupied some areas intended for the USSR and vice versa.